# change color on mouseover select menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

am trying to select a multi select combo box. There i have to customize the property that when mouse over a value the color has to change. I tried few steps i know nut its not working. Suggest me the way how should i handle it. Here is the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" >

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a="hidden";
function doset()
{
    if(a=="hidden")
    a="visible";
    else
    a="hidden";
    document.getElementById("myitems").style.visibility = a; 
}
function dochange(a)
{

    document.getElementById(a).style.background-color= 0xff00ff; 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label>ajay</label>
<input type=button value="v" onClick="doset(); return false;"/>
<div id=myitems style='visibility:hidden'>
<select multiple="multiple" >
<option id= prav1 onMouseover="dochange(this.id); return true;">ajay</option>
<option id= prav2 onMouseover="dochange(this.id); return true;">musthafa</option>
<option id= prav3 onMouseover="dochange(this.id); return true;">praveen</option>
<option id= prav4 onMouseover="dochange(this.id); return true;">shruthy</option>
<option id= prav5 onMouseover="dochange(this.id); return true;">vasanth sir</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ It should be `backgroundColor` instead of `background-color`, See my answer below.

Comment: updated my answer with working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `backgroundColor` instead of `background-color`

```
document.getElementById(a).style.backgroundColor= "#ff00ff";
```

[**SEE A WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/m7Bua/)

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById(a).style.background= "#ff00ff";

Comment: I think there is backgroundColor

Answer (score 1):

```
function dochange(a) 
{ 
  document.getElementById(a).style.backgroundColor = "#ff00ff";  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"document.getElementById(a).style.background-color" is wrong
Have to be: "document.getElementById(a).style.backgroundColor"